# Unable to git with plink

Tags: windows-7, git, putty, git-bash, msysgit

I need to configure git with putty on a windows-7 machine behind a corporate proxy. I had no problem to configure putty/pageant with a specific session for gitlab.com.

I have problems trying to configure git to use plink as ssh default command. Here are the steps that I have tried:

- I did a fresh install of git (in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Git` given that i don't own admin rights on the machine), selecting plink as the default ssh executable.
- I have added plink to the env variable. (`$ echo "$GIT_SSH"` returns
  `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`)
- I have added in .gitconfig the following lines:

```
       [core]
            editor = code --wait
            sshCommand = 'C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink.exe'

       [ssh]    
           variant = plink
```

If in git-bash, if I type `plink git@gitlab.com` works as expected, while if I type `ssh -v git@gitlab.com` I see:`OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018`
`debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Git-bash is still trying to use openssh as the ssh executable.

Is there any other way I can use to force git to use plink?
Many thanks for your help!

Git for Windows v2.21, plink 0.70.